# Map Control is not showing in Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT App

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am using Map control in my App.

I have followed the below steps to use Map control:

1) Generated **Map service ApplicationID** and **Map service AuthenticationToken** from the store.

2) Store the **Map service ApplicationID** in my **package.manifest** file.

3) Set **MapServiceToken** of Map control to **Map service AuthenticationToken**.

4) Set center property of Map using **Geopoint**.

After all these steps, still I cannot see map.

Below is the Xaml Code

```
<map:MapControl x:Name="myMapControl"
                        MapServiceToken="*********"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0" />
```

C# Code

```
void Test_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myMapControl.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Latitude = 47.604,
            Longitude = -122.329
        });
        myMapControl.ZoomLevel = 12;
        myMapControl.LandmarksVisible = true;
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I just put the map credentials straight into the XAML, not the manifest file.
<Maps:Map x:Name="myMap" Credentials="AlwRNq0HB..."/>
I assume you've downloaded the SDK as well? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @kernanb I am using **Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps**  which is provided by microsoft for Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime Applications.
Btw, I am not getting any error. Simply Map is not visible

Comment: Do you have this installed? https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/224eb93a-ebc4-46ba-9be7-90ee777ad9e1

Comment: @kernanb It is for Windows 8.1 Apps not for Windows Phone 8.1 Apps.

Comment: I know, I have a Windows 8.1 RT App (Desktop & Tablet) that uses Bing Maps and I use this SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Height and Width of MapControl.

Setting Width and Height to my MapControl solved the issue.

By default it takes 0 height.

[Thanks to **DennisBakker71**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/075d06f5-c6ad-4f0f-831a-0bdd24702b24/map-control-is-not-showing-in-windows-phone-81-winrt-app?forum=wpdevelop)